# Objective C function to generate php sha1() compatible hashes

Tags: php, objective-c, sha1

i´m trying to generate hashes in objective C which are similar to the output of php function sha1().

I´m using CC_SHA1 from the CommonCrypto Framework but my output is different. Any idea or hint how to deal with this problem?

Thanks in advance and kind regards

solick

Edit:

PHP Code:

```
$pwd = "testpassword";

echo "sha1($pwd): ".sha1($pwd);
?>
```

Objective C Code:

```
NSString *password = @"testpassword";
NSData *data = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
/* remote BOM ->Byte Order Mark */
data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[data bytes] + 2 length:[data length] - 2];

NSString *unicodePassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
data = [unicodePassword dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];


unsigned char hash[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_SHA1([data bytes], [data length], hash);
NSData *result = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
//NSLog(@"Result: %@\n",[result base64EncodedString]);
kas_auth_data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [result base64EncodedString]];
//kas_auth_data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [result ]];
NSLog(@"kas_auth_data: %@\n", kas_auth_data);
```

Output php: 
    sha1(testpassword): 8bb6118f8fd6935ad0876a3be34a717d32708ffd

Output Objective c: 
    kas_auth_data: 8uC98qEpeXx1J32yhKPdhdqNTno=

Answer (score 2):

Solved it on my own:

```
NSString* sha1_encode (NSString* input)
{
    const char *cstr = [input cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:input.length];

    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_SHA1(data.bytes, data.length, digest);

    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

    return output;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the same function, most likely PHP hex-encodes or base64-encodes the binary output of SHA1 algorithm.
Please show what you gets on both sides and your code.